# Dynamically adding views in another activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I want to add a switch dynamically in a activity when I press a button in another activity in an android app. I also would like to know if I will have to write the xml code for the switch in another layout or in the same layout in which it is to be added. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search for `startActivtyForResult()` . Find sample code and you are good to go .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not just simply press a button and make a switch into another activity since every activity has it's own life cycle and remains active until it get's destroyed and changes will reflect only if it's in **foreground** so what you can do you is when you press a button just set some **flag** that **switch** is enabled then when you land on another activity you check if the flag is enabled then make a dynamic **switch** and **add** it to the **parent layout**.

sample code: Add in the first activity where you are setting switch flag.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.switch_enable), true);
editor.commit();
```

you have saved a flag in shared preference and when you land on another activity just check the value of this flag.

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    LinearLayout parentLayout;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        parentLayout = findViewById(R.id.llParentLayout);
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = 
        this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean switchValue = sharedPref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.switch_enable), false);
        //now draw dynamic view
       Switch newSwitch = new Switch(this);
       newSwitch.setTextOn("Switch is on");
       newSwitch.setTextOff("Switch is off");
       newSwitch.setChecked(switchValue);
       parentLayout.addView(newSwitch);
    }
}
```

we have **LinearLayout** as the parent in the activity where we have added the switch.

Comment: Thanks for your help!:)

Comment: don't forget to give a thumbs up if it helps you. thanks

Comment: Can you help me with that getActivity(). It does not show any method named getActivity().

Answer (score 0):

You better add switch in the activity/layout where it wants to display.

Status of a  button is tapped or not  in another activity can be managed by passing using INTENT in android.

Read the intent value in the activity where switch wants to display.

Comment: Can you please share me a example code for the same?

Comment: Code that displays how will i add the switch when a button is pressed in another activity may be using intent as you said.